# Finding the form of all functions $f(t)$ that satisfies $f'(t) = k \cdot f(t)$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I do not know anything about differential equations.

From my textbook, it is shown that $f(t) = e^{kt}$ satisfies $f'(t) = k \cdot f(t)$. Which makes perfect sense. But then, it continues by defining a function $g(t) = e^{-kt} \cdot f(t)$.

Continuing...

\begin{align}
      g'(t) &= 0 \;\;\;\; \text{(which shows that $g$ is a constant function)}\\        
      g(t) &= e^{-kt} \cdot f(t) \\
      g(t) \cdot e^{kt} &= f(t) \\
      C \cdot e^{kt} &= f(t) \;\;\;\; \text{(where C is some constant)}\\
      f(t) &= f(0) \cdot e^{kt} \;\;\;\; \text{(I'm assuming $C = f(0)$ because $f(0) = C \cdot e^{k(0)} = C(1) = C$)}
\end{align}

This entire process makes sense to me, but the one question I have is why exactly is $g$ defined as specifically $e^{-kt} \cdot f(t)$? Is it just some function that's specifically defined with the sole purpose of showing the general form of all functions $f$ is $f(0)(e^{kt})$?

Comment: Also, assuming I erase everything I read from my memory when I take an exam, how would I go about finding $g$ or the general form of all functions $f$.

Comment: I think there is a bit missing. The proof only assumes you that $f' = kf$. Then, defining $g := e^{-kt} f$, you have that $$g' = 0 \implies g = \text{constant} = e^{-kt} f \implies f = \text{constant } \cdot e^{kt}$$ i.e you have shown the solution $f$ to the differential equation $f' = k f$ is some constant times $e^{kt}$. And $g$ is defined exactly the way it is so that $g' = 0$ and hence $g$ can be shown to be constant.

Comment: When you get to the method of integrating factors, you will see that this is simply how you solve the ODE $f'(t)=kf(t)$ using the integrating factor $e^{-kt}$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is much easier to see it like this: Let $y=f(t)$, then we have
\begin{align*}
y'&=k\cdot y\\[1mm]
\frac{dy}{dt}&=k\cdot y\\[1mm]
\frac{dy}{y}&=k\cdot dt\\[1mm]
\color{red}\int\frac{dy}{y}&=k\cdot \color{red}\int dt\\
\ln(y)&=kt+const.\\[1mm]
y&=e^{const.}\cdot e^{kt}\\[1mm]
y&=\color{red}C e^{kt}
\end{align*}
Then you get the general solution $f(t)=C e^{kt}$, when $C=f(0)$.

But to try to give an idea of what the author has in mind, it may be that you want to introduce, by way of example, the idea of "integrating factor". We have
\begin{align*}
y'&=k\cdot y\\
\color{red}{e^{-kt}}\cdot y'&=k\cdot \color{red}{e^{-kt}}\cdot y\\
\color{red}{e^{-kt}}\cdot y'-k\cdot \color{red}{e^{-kt}}\cdot y&=0\\
\color{red}{e^{-kt}}\cdot y'+\left(\color{red}{e^{-kt}}\right)'\cdot y&=0\\
\left(\color{red}{e^{-kt}}y\right)'&=0
\end{align*}
Thus, if we call $g(t)=e^{-kt}y$ you get $g'(t)=0$. This is the reason why the author takes that form for g, later on you will see a general way of how to obtain these integrating factors.

Comment: Your first solution isn't quite right, since it doesn't cover the case $y \le 0$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Sure, but keep in mind that the author of the question mentions that he does not have much knowledge of the EDO's in this case I only relied on the "idea" of what the author of the book wants to do, it is not a formal solution, even putting the absolute value remains $y=0$. I try to give you options so that you can understand what is behind the artificiality of the $g(t)$ function. For that same reason I add my other solution.